# Bonobo Git server, Windows Authentication not working 100%

Tags: bonobo

I setup a Bonobo Git server (5.0.1) but was getting an error where the windowsauthcallback was to a non-existent path.  I found some information on the this site that said this issue had been patched so I cloned it from the repository current as of 12/30/2015 and compiled.

This fixed the issue for git clients and for using a web browser from at least one Windows 8.1 machine.

However, any of the Windows 7 or Server 2008 machines just keep prompting for user name password dialog boxes even after entering the proper credentials.  On these machines I have tried using different browsers IE, Chrome and Firefox.  On IE the site is in LAN sites security group. For Firefox it is in the Integrated Authentication allowed sites.  I'm not sure where Chrome would have a similar setting.

I'm guessing its some type of security difference between Windows 7 and Windows 8.1.  I don't have a enough 8.1 machines to test if its is just the one Windows 8.1.  I have tested it on a Windows 10 machine and it has the same issues as the Windows 7 machines.

Using the git clients from the Windows 7 machines works for both cloning, pulling and pushing the remote repository.  Both the mingw64 Git and that with Tortoise Git's wincred Credential Helper.

Any help getting the Windows 7 machines Web access to the repositories would be appreciated.

What my goal for this is to put all of the scripts (linux and windows) that our server infrastructure team uses into version control. To remove the problem of various versions used on new servers depending on where the person got the script from.  We would then also have a way for the people that only use the scripts a easy way to access the latest version.  I figured using Bonobo's web access url in our server setup documentation would be the best way to do this.

Sorry for the wall of text and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to version 5.1.1 and issue has gone away.  Thanks.